# Open policy agent define dynamic global variable

Tags: terraform, open-policy-agent, rego

I was wondering if there's any way to prettify my code as it looks terribly inefficient and totally not DRY. What I'm trying to achieve is to pull a specific resource out of a list of resources (a resource named "aks" out of a terraform plan), and run some tests against it. Problem is, I am using the `some` keyword to get it which prevents me from configuring a global variable, which causes a lot of repetition, for example:

```
aks_default_pool_type_vmss {
    some index
    input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index].type == "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster"
    aks := input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index]
    aks.values.default_node_pool[0].type == "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
}

aks_system_assigned_identity {
    some index
    input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index].type == "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster"
    aks := input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index]
    aks.values.identity[_].type == "SystemAssigned"
}
```

Is there any way to create a "global" variable which will catch the aks resource, in order to prevent all of the re-calculation?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a rule who creates a set of aks objects (See generating [sets in the OPA documentation](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#generating-sets)):

```
clusters[aks] {
    some index
    input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index].type == "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster"
    aks := input.planned_values.root_module.resources[index]
}
```

And then your rules can rewrite your to the following:

```
aks_default_pool_type_vmss {
    aks := clusters[_]
    aks.values.default_node_pool[0].type == "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
}

aks_system_assigned_identity {
    aks := clusters[_]
    aks.values.identity[_].type == "SystemAssigned"
}
```